# Page stalling although appearing to be fully loaded

Tags: javascript, dom, load

I have a page which appears to load fully, but I actually have to wait a further 6-10 seconds for things like buttons to become fully functional.

In IE you can still see the browser loading bar at full for this time after the page displays.

Does anyone know why this might be? I stripped out all the javascript and it still does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was the way the page was rendering from the asp:repeater

Instead I created a datagrid and it seemed to eliminate the problem. No idea why as I'd expect it to be the other way around if anything.

Answer (score 0):

I get that in my pages sometimes when I don't compress my images.  Large image files, or other large media, would be the first place I would check.

Something else I normally look for in speeding up the page is time it takes to download services (feed parsing etc), though since you took out all your javascript that shouldn't be a problem.